# Set WH_GETMESSAGE hook makes the system dead

Tags: windows, setwindowshookex

I use SetWindowsHookEx to install a global GETMESSAGE hook in a dll like this:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE,HookProc,hModule,0);
```

and the the hook procedure within the dll too.But when i called InstallHook(this function is exported from the DLL) to install the GETMESSAGE hook,booom, the system can not respon the mouse operation,the windows on the desktop can be close or move) ,here is my HookProc Code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    WCHAR szMsg[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    PMSG pMsg = (PMSG)lParam;
    wsprintf(szMsg, L"MSG_FROM:%08x,MSG_TYPE:%d", pMsg->hwnd,pMsg->message);
    OutputDebugString(szMsg);
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL,nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I've read the MSDN for many times,it just said i must process the message if the ncode is HC_ACTION,but,i don't know how to process the message.I think there must be someone else has this problem too, so, hope somebody give some help, and tell me how you process this trouble.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you install your hook? Do you have a DLL with your hook routine exported? Do you have the same effect if instead of `WH_GETMESSAGE` you use another hook kind? Because this may be due to improper hook installation

Comment: @valdo I install the hook from the exe by using the exported function[InstallHook] in the dll.I don't know this sentence from MSDN "if ncode is HC_ACTION you must process this message",so how should i process message?